# none latin names of variables in c#

Tags: c#

I have named my button object (WinForms) with all hebrew letters and then added click event... and it worked.

Is this some new lang feature I've missed?

```
this.כפתור = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
this.SuspendLayout();
// 
// כפתור
// 
this.כפתור.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(58, 48);
this.כפתור.Name = "כפתור";
this.כפתור.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
this.כפתור.TabIndex = 0;
this.כפתור.Text = "button1";
this.כפתור.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
this.כפתור.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
כפתור.Text = "BLAH BLAH";
}
```

Comment: I believe so. What was your question?

Comment: Nothing new but, C# source code is unicode so pretty much anything goes ...

Comment: @Jannis, I'm not familiar with this feat. My friends asked me and got me with surprise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# (also other popular languages like Java) uses unicode character set for its source code. It is not anything new.

I would suggest you not only stick to English letters but also stick to English names for identifiers. It keeps the program naming consistent with the framework and the source code can be maintained by programmers who don't understand your language.

Comment: But I think Java uses ASCII as default source file encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The C# language specification shows what you can and cannot use for identifiers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

It basically says that unicode characters are permitted for certain sets of characters, and I'm assuming the set that includes Hebrew is in that list. (I don't know the set name for Hebrew characters sets)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like unicode variable names have been supported for some time, though I've never used them.
http://jameskovacs.com/2006/02/16/unicode-variable-names/